# Make column width same as another column width

Tags: wpf

In my WPF app I have 2 grids inside a parent grid:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="col1 width"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="col2 width"/>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    </Grid>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" x:Name="col1"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" x:Name="col2"/>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

How can I bind the width of the column definitions in the first grid to the other grid?

Comment: It would be possible to set up a binding, but that would be silly. WPF provides a good mechanism for automatically ensuring grid columns are the same width across multiple grids. There are already many questions on Stack Overflow asking what you've asked, with answers. See the three duplicates referred to above, for example.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this

```xml
<Grid>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=col1, Path=Width}"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=col2, Path=Width}"/>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    </Grid>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" x:Name="col1"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" x:Name="col2"/>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: The xaml can't find `col1` or `col2` because of their level in the xaml.

Comment: You could write the binding in C# where you have access to them.

Answer (score 1):

I tested the below code and it works well.

```
<Grid >
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=col1, Path=ActualWidth}"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=col2, Path=ActualWidth}"/>
         </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    </Grid>
    <Grid >
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100" x:Name="col1"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="150" x:Name="col2"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    </Grid>
```